# Why is HTML not updating after HTTP get request executes?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search field that receives some value to search and populates an array. If the value the user provides is invalid a boolean is set to true, displaying an error message and the input's outline color changes to red.

I have a function that receives the value provided and makes an `HTTP` get request. Inside the `.subscribe()` function I update the error message and change the input's outline color to red.

I've searched for similar problems and found that most of the cases involved people not updating variables inside the subscription, however that is not the case with my code.

**MyComponent.component.ts**

```
constructor(public rest: RestService) { }

private onCreateNewRequest(value: any) {
  let message = "Required!";
  if (value === undefined || value === "" || value.length < 0) {
    this.setErrorMessage(message);
    this.setIsFormInvalid(true);
    this.setNewRequestInputInvalid()
  } else {
    this.getOrderByNumber(this.setNewRequestInputInvalid, value);
  }
}

private getOrderByNumber(callback, value: string) {
  let message = "Invalid Order!";
  this.rest.getOrderByNumber(value).subscribe((orderNrData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderNrData).length !== 0) {
      this.onCreateReturn(orderNrData);
    } else {
      callback();
      this.setErrorMessage(message);
      this.setIsFormInvalid(true);
    }
  }, error => {
    callback();
    this.setErrorMessage(message);
    this.setIsFormInvalid(true);
  });
}

private setErrorMessage(message: string) {
  this.errorMessage = message;
}

private setIsFormInvalid(status: boolean) {
  this.isFormInvalid = status;
}

private setNewRequestInputInvalid() {
  document.getElementById('new-request-input-id').style['border-color'] = 'red';
}
```

**MyComponent.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 d-flex align-items-center">Order: </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <input class="form-control align-middle new-request-input-class" id="new-request-input-id" type="text" placeholder="Ex: EU030327" aria-label="Search" (input)="resetValidator()" (keyup.enter)="onCreateNewRequest(searchInput.value)" #searchInput>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-8 error-label-col" id="error-label-id" *ngIf="isFormInvalid">
    <small>{{getErrorMessage()}}</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Rest.service.ts**

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res;
  return body || {};
}

getOrderByNumber(order_nr): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(endpoint + 'orders/number/' + order_nr, httpOptions).pipe(
            map(this.extractData));
}
```

My code successfully changes the input's outline color to red but somehow fails to change `isFormInvalid` to true. Because of this, the `*ngIf` won't trigger and the message is never shown to the user.

**EDIT:**

If I use `ChangeDetectorRef` after I change `isFormInvalid` everything works as expected...

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

private getOrderByNumber(callback, value: string) {
  let message = "Invalid Order!";
  this.rest.getOrderByNumber(value).subscribe((orderNrData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderNrData).length !== 0) {
      this.onCreateReturn(orderNrData);
    } else {
      callback();
      this.setErrorMessage(message);
      this.setIsFormInvalid(true);
      this.ref.detectChanges(); // here
    }
  }, error => {
    callback();
    this.setErrorMessage(message);
    this.setIsFormInvalid(true);
    this.ref.detectChanges(); // here
  });
}
```

Why is Angular only detecting these changes if I force it to detect them? Also, is this a good practice?

Comment: Are you using some `ChangeDetectionStrategy`?

Comment: Do you mean like `ChangeDetectorRef`? I tried and it works but I was looking for a solution that didn't involve forcing Angular to detect a change...

Comment: build in some loggin at every function and see what the values are every time the properties are updated and the functions are executed. Check if and when the functions are executed.

Comment: No, I mean, in case you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, it would explain your problem

Comment: @Antonis No, I don't use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: @Napinator I tried to print the value of my variables every time I changed them and the changes appear correctly, for some reason `*ngIf` won't update unless I use `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: Based on what you have listed, I don't see anything obvious.  But I can say that I have had my run ins with ChangeDetectorRef and needing it.  It seems to be an issue whenever the thing I'm relying on might be outside of the angular zone.  I would take a look at a couple of areas to see what is happening there.  1) what is this.rest and does it do anything that might cause it to execute outside of the angular zone.  2) document.getElementById is definitely against the recommendations and can cause some pretty odd behavior.  Better to bind to the style directly using [style.border-color].

Comment: @ccamac Thanks! I'll take a look at `ChangeDetectorRef` so I can further understand it... About does other questions: 1) `this.rest` refers to a service that executes the get requests (I updated my code); 2) How do I do that without using `getElementById`?

Comment: @ccamac That styling tip was a no-brainer, don't know how I'd never thought of that. Thanks again!

Comment: @H.Soares looking over the whole thing again, I am willing to bet that the issue is coming from your callback() line.  But here is the best suggestion I can make.  Comment that line out and see if it fixes the issue.  If not, keep commenting out lines in there one by one until the issue is solved.  Then you will know which line is causing it to fall outside of the angular zone.  Then you can work on that problem specifically.  Like maybe wrapping it in an ngZone.run() or something like that.  Or maybe  just refactoring it til you can get it recognize the change detection.